# ReactJS DOM dynamic refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that contains rows and I want to be able to use getDOMNode to modify the DOM.

Normally I would define the ref of the component ref="mytable" and then get the ref using  this.refs.mytable.getDOMNode();  I want to be able to create the ref name depending on an id.

How can I get that DOM with the ref={"row" + val.id)?
I tried using brackets this.refs['row' + i]getDOMNode(); but I still get an error, here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ux4rL8sf/4/

```
onRowClick: function (i) {
  var x = this.refs['row' + i]getDOMNode();
  //Do Something with x
},
var Items = this.state.currentItems.map(function(val) {
  return (
    <tr ref={"row" + val.id} onClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this, val.id) }> </tr>
   )
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there, just use the bracket notation like this

```
onRowClick: function (i) {
  var x = this.refs['row' + i].getDOMNode();
  //Do Something with x
}
```

Comment: Fixed the issues see this fiddle instead: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ux4rL8sf/4/
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined

Comment: Using this.refs is deprecated